# How to store votes with cookies in PHP/JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Somewhere on the web I seen a site that has a basic "like" script for blog posts.

I am trying to replicate it, I am just a little confused.  Here is the code I have for the frontend

Javascript, requires jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

function my_reloadLikes(who) {
    var text = jQuery("#" + who).html();
    var patt= /(\d)+/;

    var num = patt.exec(text);
    num[0]++;
    text = text.replace(patt,num[0]);
    jQuery("#" + who).html('<span class="count">' + text + '</span>');
} //reloadLikes


function my_likeInit() {
    jQuery(".likeThis").click(function() {
        var classes = jQuery(this).attr("class");
        classes = classes.split(" ");

        if(classes[1] == "active") {
            return false;
        }
        var classes = jQuery(this).addClass("active");
        var id = jQuery(this).attr("id");
        id = id.split("like-");
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "index.php",
          data: "likepost=" + id[1],
          success: my_reloadLikes("like-" + id[1])
        }); 


        return false;
    });
}

my_likeInit();

});
```

HTML

```
.like-count .icon {
    background-position: 0 -19px;
    width: 13px;
    height: 11px;
    float: left;
    margin: 4px 5px 0 0;
}

.like-count a:hover .icon,
.like-count a.active .icon { background-position: -15px -19px; }

.like-count,
.edit-post,
.comment-count {
     float: right;
     margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

<li class="like-count">
    <a href="#" class="likeThis active" id="like-356">
      <span class="count"><span class="icon"></span>
      <span class="count">397</span></span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Here is what I have gathered so far...

my_likeInit() function

- Adds a click event to the .likeThis class
- Saves the likeThis class to a variable
- Splits the value of .likeThis if there is a " " space, it is checking
  to see if there is an "active" class attached to it or not
- If .active is found then it dies as this has alread been voted/liked
  for
- If not,  it adds the .active class to .likeThis
- Then it gets the id=like-123number
- Splits it and cuts of the "like-" part and gets the number
- Send the id number to the PHP script as "likepost=NUMBERHERE
- On success from the AJAX request, it runs the  my_reloadLikes()
  function, passing in the value "like-NUMBERHERE"

my_reloadLikes() function

- I wont go into it but you can see, it finds the div by ID number and
  adds the number and then updates the number on the page

When I run firebug, under Net / XHR I get this,

**Request Headers**
`POST:  likepost=811`  *//in this case, I had clicked to vote on id 811*
`w3tc_referrer=http%3A%2F%2Ftest.testdomain.com%2F%3Ftheme%3Dtest; 795=795; 835=835; 832=832`  This is some sort of cookie being set that appears to save the id of all the things I vote/like on.

**Response Headers**
`Set-Cookie 811=811; expires=Sat, 13-Jan-2807 11:04:20 GMT; path=/`  Here I can see the id is definitively being saved to a cookie.  TO me it looks like this would be it's OWN cookie, but above it shows multiple values in the cookie, so are they just appended onto the end?  All those ID's that I voted on above were on the same page, possibly it is 1 cookie per page, hopefully just 1 per site...

---

So that is as far as I am, I have basically dissected the code and I fully understand everything above, now on the the back-end which will be out of my head and where I need help

Ok when a page loads, I will populate the like count from a MySQL database, I know how to do the backend of adding the values and getting the values for this script.  The cookie part is where I am a little confused.

I just did another test, I now see that the script DOES save each vote into a seperate cookie, so if I vote on 100 items I have 100 cookies for that site, that doesn't seem right?

Is there a better way?  The cookies identify if I have already voted and prevent me from voting again until my cookies are cleared.  This will be on a wordpress blog so the users will not be logged in, so there isn't a lot of options besides cookies and/or IP address.

Questions

1. Is there a better way to keep track of which items I have voted/liked instead of a cookie for each item?
2. Some sample PHP code to check for a cookie so I can add a "active" class to items that are already voted on (based on if they have a cookie for it)
3. ON a wordpress blog, how can I POST to index.php?likepost=1234 or am I better of just posting to a different URI page and doing a DB connection manually instead of utilizing the wordpress stuff?

=========
Thanks for any insight on the cookie issues, I realize I kinda rambled on there a bit.

Comment: To answer #1, serialization is a great way to store multiple data entries in one entity. http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/. However, I wouldn't do this using cookies - They can be easily modified by the user and screw your logic up.

Comment: So how would you recommend?  Storing in DB?

Comment: I would recommend storing votes/likes in DB. This is the logical way. As you know cookies are client side. You should check from DB whether the user voted or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely do this in the database. As I said earlier, cookies can be modified and really screw up your logic. Create a simple database table:

```
-------------------------------
|            likes            |
-------------------------------
| like_id | post_id | user_id |
-------------------------------
```

Create a primary key (auto increment) on `like_id`, so you can easily delete rows. Then create a `UNIQUE` index on `post_id, user_id`, which will help in data concurrency as it is impossible for a user to like the same post more than once at the database level.

However, you can omit `like_id` if you prefer. It is not necessary, and all up to your preference.

Now, you can query out any information you need. Say, the number of likes for a post:

```
SELECT COUNT( *) FROM likes WHERE post_id = $post_id
```

Or to determine whether or not a user liked this post:

```
SELECT like_id FROM likes WHERE post_id = $post_id AND user_id = $user_id
```

To address the rest of your questions:

1. As I said earlier, serialization is a common and great practice to store multiple entries in one entity. Essentially you are saving the state of an object (or array) so that it can be restored later. However, if you use the DB, you won't need to serialize a JS array / object, but it is good to know about as it comes in handy.
2. Add an active class based on a query from the database, see above.
3. Definitely POST to index.php?likepost=1234. This maintains a single entry point into your application, which WordPress provides for you. The benefits for this are obvious - Let WordPress setup your connection to the DB and provide you with all the functionality you need instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: thanks for the tips, my main reason for considering the cookie version was because there is no user_id, all viewers are guest, so the only way would be to use IP which as you know isn't the best solution

Comment: If you want to do that, use cookies for only guests and don't let their likes affect the database. Then, who cares if they mess with the cookies, they're only messing with the display on their side. Just keep in mind when you create the cookie portion that you can't trust that the cookie isn't modified by the user.